# How to set different positions for each point with Points node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to simply use the Points node as an initial parameter for instantiating objects in my geometry nodes, Think of it as a grid but with only 1 line
But I don't get the way to set each point instance a different position.
[image: Points Node]

Comment: Just use the node `Mesh Line` instead. There you can specify a direction of the line and the number of points.

Comment: tbh start watching basic beginner geometry nodes tutorial - e.g. Erindale make great GN tutorials

Comment: use the index and plug it into the position and do some math to get it how you want